# Putting multiple values as single strings into object

Tags: javascript

I have an object `values`:

```
values = [{
    stringValues: "First value",
    kind: "stringValues"
  },
  {
    stringValues: "Second Value",
    kind: "stringValues"
  },
]
```

I need to extract the `stringValues` and put them into another object `obj` as a value to the key `ghi`. The final result should look like that:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "abc": {
    "def": "def",
    "ghi": ["First Value", "Second Value"]
  }
}
```

My approach is :

```
var valuesStr = "";
values.forEach(
  (v) => {
    valuesStr += `'${v.stringValues}',`
  }
);

obj = {
  name: "name",
  abc: {
    def: "def",
    ghi: valuesStr,
  },
};
```

But the result doesn't look quite right:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "abc": {
    "def": "def",
    "ghi": "'First value','Second Value',"
  }
}
```

As you can see, it puts both values as 1 string.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zrx0sp76/

Comment: In your final result you describe an **array** of strings, not one single concatenated string.

Comment: An [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) would do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want it be an array, then declare it as an array and push() values to it.

```
var valuesArr = [];
values.forEach(
  (v) => {
    valuesArr.push(v.stringValues);
  }
);

obj = {
  name: "name",
  abc: {
    def: "def",
    ghi: valuesArr,
  },
};
```